# Hosting two web applications on same server

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, httpd, web-applications, httpd.conf

Without giving all the details, I'm trying to set up (via apache) two web applications that will be served from the same (internal development) server. Currently I have two `VirtualHost` directives and the two applications running on different ports. Instead, I'd like to have the URL determine which application is used, so, for example, `myapp.domain.com` will forward to one application and any other `.domain.com` will go to the other. Setting up the internal DNS to take care of that piece isn't a problem. But I'm not very familiar with apache, what's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the `<VirtualHost>` you can use a `ServerName`; this is the directive to tell Apache to handle requests for that particular name. You can also use `ServerAlias` to specify other domains (and more besides!) that you'd like the `VirtualHost` to handle requests for.

For example, you can set up your directives like this

```
<VirtualHost ...>
    ServerName foo.example.com
    ...
    #Handle webapp1 in here
    ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost ....>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    ...
    #Handle webapp2 in here
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

The Apache documentation contains several very good examples for most use cases in their documentation (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html). You may also be interested in their "*default*" catchall [halfway down the page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html#default), which is basically a catchall for any virtual host requests that aren't matched by previous directives.